# Navigating or transforming JSON with Linq

Tags: c#, json, linq

Let consider this JSON

```json
{
  "data": "014",
  "theme": "COLORADO CASUAL",
  "family": "2163",
  "category": "00",
  "compo_groups": [
    {
      "title": "HEAD024",
      "values": [
        {
          "perc": "100",
          "desc": "COMP036"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "HEAD035",
      "values": [
        {
          "perc": "100",
          "desc": "COMP042"
        },
        {
          "perc": "50",
          "desc": "COMP043"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "product_name": "D812",
  "supplier_code": "1011"
}
```

I need to check that all my compositions are exactly 100pc. In this JSON I have 2 group of composition. The first one is correct. I have one element to 100pc. The second one is composed by 2 elements and total is 150pc. This is an error.

I need to write a code in C# that detect the error. I can write most part of this code. I just don't know how to transform this JSON in list of values I can manage with LinQ.

Comment: Have you tried parsing the json in classes and process those?

Comment: Also what json library are you using?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't had time to finalize properly the question. I'm now using the System.Text.Json. I'm used to the Newtonsoft one but the Microsoft one seems the same. I will add here what I alreadu tried.

Comment: I'm using ```System.Text.Json.Nodes.JsonObject``` and ```System.Text.Json.Nodes.JsonNode```.
I deserialize using ```System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>```.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using a recent version of .NET (e.g. .NET6) then you can use the built-in [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=net-7.0) libraries to parse your JSON input. If you need to use other parts of the JSON, I would recommend deserialising in to concrete C# classes so you get proper validation, IntelliSense and all that good stuff.

However, if you simply want to check those percentages you can use the STJ library directly, something like this for example:

```
// Load JSON 
var json = "{...}";
var doc = JsonDocument.Parse(json);

// Manually walk the document to get the values you need and summarise
var result = doc.RootElement
    .GetProperty("compo_groups")
    .EnumerateArray()
    .Select(a => new 
    {
        Title = a.GetProperty("title").ToString(),
        Percentage = a.GetProperty("values")
            .EnumerateArray()
            .Select(v => double.Parse(v.GetProperty("perc").ToString()))
            .Sum()
    });
```

And you can iterate over that result like this:

```
foreach(var value in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Title '{value.Title}' has a percentage of {value.Percentage}");
}
```

Which will output this:

```
Title 'HEAD024' has a percentage of 100
Title 'HEAD035' has a percentage of 150
```

Comment: The key is to use ```System.Text.Json.JsonDocument```

Answer (score 3):

you don't need any classes to get the data you want

```
using System.Text.Json;

List<string> titles = JsonNode.Parse(json)["compo_groups"].AsArray()
                         .Select(x => x["values"].AsArray())
                         .Where(v => v.Select(x => 
                          Convert.ToInt32(x["perc"].GetValue<string>())).Sum() > 100)
                         .Select(v => v.Parent["title"].GetValue<string>())
                         .ToList();  // result  ["HEAD035"]
```

or

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

List<string> titles = JObject.Parse(json)["compo_groups"]
    .Select(x => x["values"])
    .Where(v => v.Select(x => (int)x["perc"]).Sum() > 100)
    .Select(v => v.Parent.Parent)
    .Select(p=> (string) p["title"]) // here you can select any data you need
    .ToList();  // result  ["HEAD035"]
```

Comment: You are using the ```Parse()``` then the ```AsArray()```. This is similar to what I did with JsonNode. I got exception on AsArray() all the time. I will try again to figure out what I did wrong. Thank you for your help.